# Improving data.table subsetting performance

Tags: r, performance, data.table, subset, benchmarking

I am running a large monte-carlo simulation, and I discovered that sub-setting/searching my data is the slowest part of my code. In order to test some alternatives, I bench-marked performance with dataframes, data.table, and a matrix.
Here is the benchmark code:

```
library(data.table)
#install.packages('profvis')
library(profvis)
x.df = data.frame(a=sample(1:10,10000,replace=T), b=sample(1:10,10000,replace=T)) # set up a dataframe
x.dt = as.data.table(x.df) # a data.table
setkey(x.dt,a) # set key for faster searches
x.mat = as.matrix(x.df) # a matrix

profvis({
for (i in 1:10000) {
  # test simple subsetting
  xsubset.mat = x.mat[100:200,2]
  xsubset.df = x.df[100:200,2]
  xsubset.dt = x.dt[100:200,2]
  # test search preformance
  xsearch.mat = x.mat[which(x.df$a==10),2]
  xsearch.df = x.df[which(x.df$a==10),2]
  xsearch.dt = x.dt[.(10),2]
}
})
```

Here are my results: 
[image: benchmark scores]
In all seriousness, I love the compact syntax of data.table, and I am wondering if there is something I can do to improve its performance. According to the  creators, its supposed to be super fast. Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: think about using the parallel package for your monte carlo simulation to run your code on multiple cores

Comment: I could understand slower subsets, given that `[i, j]` can do so many things depending on the expression, there's gotta be an overhead for initial checks. The slower search does strike me as odd.

Comment: If your x.dt is the same over these many iterations and the lookup/search is for integers like a, just precompute the subsets and store them in a list. `bs = split(x.dt$b, x.dt$a)` and access like `bs[[1]]` as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more benchmarking, I now understand the issue. The fastest package depends on whether I'm doing many small searches or one big search. It seems that data.table has a lot of overhead per search, making it more suited for working with one huge table, not many searches on small ones.

Consider the following code, and compare with the original:

```
# make a giant table, but search it only once:
x.df = data.frame(a=sample(1:10,100000000,replace=T), b=sample(1:10,100000000,replace=T))
x.dt = as.data.table(x.df)
setkey(x.dt,a)
x.mat = as.matrix(x.df)

profvis({
for (i in 1:1) {
  xsubset.mat = x.mat[100:200,2]
  xsubset.df = x.df[100:200,2]
  xsubset.dt = x.dt[100:200,2]

  xsearch.mat = x.mat[which(x.df$a==10),2]
  xsearch.df = x.df[which(x.df$a==10),2]
  xsearch.dt = x.dt[.(10),2]
}
})
```

Results:
[image: searching one big table]

Comment: There is not much meaning for "time" in searches on small data sets. Even if it takes "much" longer it is still in nanoseconds so no one cares really. data.table indeed has an overhead when it comes to nanoseconds. Though, time only matters when we scale to milliseconds/seconds/etc- this when it becomes painful and this is when data.table shines and this is the idea behind it the first place. No one would create a package in order to improve performance in nanoseconds in R

Comment: Hence, your statement of "*data.table has a lot of overhead per search*" is pretty meaningless. You should test big datasets many times (not a single time) and then see how much overhead it has.